# unknown problems with php login

Tags: php, authentication, mysqli

i'm new to here, nice to meet you all ^_^

I'm having a project that to implement a simple website which allow user to login
i try to search around online but still have no idea how to fix it.
below are the code(login.php) that i written after referring to several source.

```
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM attendant WHERE username = ?")))
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else
{
    if(!($stmt->bind_param('s',$username)))
    {
        echo "bind parameter failed";
    }
    else
    {
        if(!($stmt->execute()))
        {
            echo "Execute Failed:(" . $stmt->errno .")". $stmt->error;
        }
        else
        {
                $res = $stmt->get_result();
                while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
                {
                    if($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password && $row["status"] == $status)
                    {
                        $_SESSION['user']=$username;
                        header("Location: test.html?user=$username");
                    }
                    else if($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password && $row["status"] != $status)
                    {
                        header("Location: test.html?user=$username#verify-slide");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        header("Location: test.html?Login=Fail#login-slide");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $stmt->close();

}
```

the login works perfectly when the username does exist in the database.
But if it's not, the function are not working anymore and will only stay at the login.php file.

Comment: try adding some statement on the third "else". like else if($row["username"] != $username && $row["password"] != $password && $row["status"] != $status).

Comment: tried to add that , it will become straight not functioning when the username available but password are wrong. but if using else if($row["username"] != $username Or $row["password"] != $password) then it can be use but only check password not the username..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no matched record in db, then it will **not** come into the while loop.

Add `exit();` right after `head(...)`, and put `header("Location: test.html?Login=Fail#login-slide");` outside the while loop.

And the while loop is not necessary, you could change your code like:

```
$res = $stmt->get_result();
if ($row = $res->fetch_assoc() && $row["password"] == $password) {
    if($row["status"] == $status) {
        $_SESSION['user']=$username;
        header("Location: test.html?user=$username");
    } else {
        header("Location: test.html?user=$username#verify-slide");
    }
} else {
   header("Location: test.html?Login=Fail#login-slide");
}
exit();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there aren't any matches to the username then you never enter the while loop.  That means your script will continue to the end.  You should first put an `exit()` statement after each header call.  Then you should do whatever you want to do in the event that the username name doesn't exist after the while loop.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this :

```
if(!($stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT * FROM attendant WHERE username = ?")))
{
    echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
}
else
{
    if(!($stmt->bind_param('s',$username)))
    {
       echo "bind parameter failed";
    }
else
{
    if(!($stmt->execute()))
    {
        echo "Execute Failed:(" . $stmt->errno .")". $stmt->error;
    }
    else
    {
            $res = $stmt->get_result();
            if($res->mysqli_num_rows()==0)
            {
                 header("Location: test.html?Login=Fail#login-slide");
            }
            else
            {  
              while($row = $res->fetch_assoc())
              {
                if($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password && $row["status"] == $status)
                {
                    $_SESSION['user']=$username;
                    header("Location: test.html?user=$username");
                }
                else if($row["username"] == $username && $row["password"] == $password && $row["status"] != $status)
                {
                    header("Location: test.html?user=$username#verify-slide");
                }                   
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
$stmt->close();

}
```